# electron. All of the BrowserWindows are a same session

Tags: electron

My code:

```
let w1 = new BrowserWindow();
let w2 =  new BrowserWindow();
w1.webContents.session == w2.webContents.session
```

The result is true.
It's my wrong ? Is The web content's session a default session?  If so，How can i  get the different session in different browser web content?

I try to config:

```
let w1 = new  BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences : {  session: newSession  }
})
```

when new a BrowserWindow object. But newSession.setProxy() or w1.webContents.session.setProxy() will be dose not work.

Comment: what is newSession set to exactly? Is it by chance equal to the default session? What if you tried using the [`partition`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) option

Comment: The newSession:import { session } from 'electron'; let newSession = session.fromPartition('persist:new-${key}'); It is same result when use the partition option. My electron's version is 2.0.0